# Negate parameter expansion in fish shell

Tags: fish, glob

Let's say in the I have all these files in the a directory:

```
$ ls
file1 file2 file3 file4 ... file200
```

I want to remove all files but `file4`. In `zsh` I'm used to do like this:

```
$ rm ^file4
```

How would I do this with `fish`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way.

```
set files *
set i 1; for f in $files; test $f = file4; and break; or set i (math $i+1); end
set -e files[$i]
echo rm $files
```

Since fish aims to be lean, there's not much in the way of array or filename manipulation. You might as well stick to a plain loop:

```
for f in *; test $f != file4; and echo rm $f; end
```

Note the code example at http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#continue

Comment: Frankly I still jump into bash to do stuff. My fingers are still unlearning the bash vi readline mode.

Comment: Well, this is quite verbose but it could be recycled into a custom function. I'll leave the question unanswered for a while in case something else comes along.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `find` command, which is more powerful in general. Although a bit more unconvenient to write.

```
find . -not -name file4 -type f | xargs rm
```

**Edit**

A shorter one for the simpler use cases:

```
ls | grep -v file4 | xargs rm
```

Comment: True, it may be easier in the end to forget about globbing.